# Terminology question - closed-form QA graph networks

Tags: graphs, research, graph-neural-network

I'm trying to find graph network research on closed-form sequential question answering, but whenever I include 'question-answering' I of course see cutting edge research into free-form conversational, generative chat-bots.

Instead, I'm trying to find papers that cover research into discrete question answering, where neither the human nor the 'bot' can either type or generate text. For example, a user goes to an interactive widget to diagnose a problem with a dishwasher, which on the backend is built to show a series of hard-coded questions, with multiple-choice answers, the selection of which will then show another question etc, until a problem is diagnosed and the widget can display a hard-coded solution.

I'd like to use graph networks to model these 'paths' and use neural networks to capture the sequential nature of the displayed text and user-response - but I have no idea how to search for relevant literature.

Some terms I've investigated include:

- information flow
- cascade graphs
- clickstream graphs
- multiple-choice discourse
- discriminative question-answering
- boolean question-answering
- sequential document-document

Ultimately my objective is to use graph-RNNs to produce an embedding for a single path of question-answer-question-answer-solution, where each question tries to understand more about the users problem i.e. "Is the pipe connected? (yes/no)"

Any advice on how to name this type of problem, or any relevant research papers would be greatly appreciated.